# How to push value into key[] in jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have such `jsonb` structure in Postgres table: `{ "res": [123, 223] }` and I want to push values into `res`-array. I don't know how many values there is on array and as `jsonb_insert` operates on position, so I tried with `-1` position:

```
select jsonb_insert( '{"res": [123, 223]}', '{res,-1}', '333');
       jsonb_insert       
--------------------------
 {"res": [123, 333, 223]}
```

It does not work. How to push new values to the end of array?

I am using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-1` index along with `insert_after = true`:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert( '{"res": [123, 456, 789, 101112]}', '{res, -1}', '333', true);

+-------------------------------------+
|jsonb_insert                         |
+-------------------------------------+
|{"res": [123, 456, 789, 101112, 333]}|
+-------------------------------------+
```

The default value of `insert_after` is `false`, meaning that although you're targeting the last element (index = -1), you end up inserting in the second to last position:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert( '{"res": [123, 456, 789, 101112]}', '{res, -1}', '333', false);

+-------------------------------------+
|jsonb_insert                         |
+-------------------------------------+
|{"res": [123, 456, 789, 333, 101112]}|
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use ridiculously big position:

```
select jsonb_insert( '{"res": [123, 223]}', '{res,1000000}', '333');
       jsonb_insert       
--------------------------
 {"res": [123, 223, 333]}
```