# How to add to json array in postgres?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and Postgres to databse operation and I create this column:

```
@Entity()
export class SomeTable {
    @Column({
        type: 'json',
        nullable: true,
    })
    comments: Array<Comment>;
}
```

how can I push to this array a new item during update of the whole table?

right now I'm doing this in this way:

```
const someTable = await this.entityManger.getRepository(SomeTable).findOne(id);
someTable.comments.push({something: "sdfs"});
await this.entityManger.getRepository(SomeTable).save(someTable)
```

but in this way I'm doing two query to postgres but I want to make everything in one query.

can someobody tell me how to do this?

thanks for any help!

Comment: This is doable in postgresql using a `jsonb` column instead of a `json` column (which I would highly recommend if you're doing anything more than simply storing a "valid json text value" in the database for later use, and even then `jsonb` would probably be better anyway) with the `jsonb_insert` function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313971/how-to-push-value-into-key-in-jsonb-column)). I don't know TypeORM though so I can' help you on how to actually call this function from the JS side of things.